# FileSystemProvider for Umbraco v6.1

Tags: c#, azure, blob, umbraco

I'm trying to create a new MediaFileSystemProvider which seamlessly stores Media in Azure Blob Storage.

I copied the MediaFileSystem class from Umbraco v6.1 source for my starting point.

I then edited the /config/FileSystemProviders.config file inserting my new class details.

When I restart Umbraco, the new class is called but I get the error:

"Could not find constructor for type 'mysite.core.umbracoExtensions.FileSystemProviders.AzureBlobStorageProvider, mysite.core' which accepts 0 parameters"

Here's my class:

...

```
[FileSystemProvider("media")]
public class AzureBlobStorageProvider : FileSystemWrapper
{
    private string rootUrl;
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudBlobClient blobClient;
    CloudBlobContainer container;

    public AzureBlobStorageProvider(IFileSystem wrapped)
        : base(wrapped)
    {

        var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(constring);

        // Create the blob client.
        blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mymedia");

        //container.CreateIfNotExists();
        //container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

        rootUrl = "https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/media";
    }
```

...

methods

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't leave this half done considering all the help I've received from folks here :)

I setup a fresh Umbraco v6.1.6 and confirmed the MediaService.Deleted event definitely does not get fired/hooked for me with the below code.  I'll go find out how to submit a bug...

For anyone else interested in storing Umbraco Media Items in Azure Storage, below is how I did it.  You can turn the CDN on/off for displaying image content with the "CDNEnabled" key and turn uploading on/off with the "AzureCDNUploadEnabled" key without having to touch your Views each time.

FYI, the actual CDN part of Azure Blob Storage is not available at the moment.  It was and now isn't and apparently will be again some day.

You can limit your data usage and speed up image delivery by setting the "AzureCDNCacheControlHeader" value to update the Cache-Control header as you upload.  The values below set the images to expire in 30 days and then revalidate.

Add this to your web.config appsettings node:

```
    <!-- cdn config -->

    <!-- used for razor rendering -->
    <add key="CDNPath" value="https://utest.blob.core.windows.net"/>
    <add key="CDNEnabled" value="true"/>

    <!-- used for media uploads -->
    <add key="AzureCDNStorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={yourAccount};AccountKey={yourKey}"/>
    <add key="AzureCDNStorageAccountName" value="{yourStorageAccount}"/>
    <add key="AzureCDNBlobContainerName" value="media"/>
    <add key="AzureCDNRootUrl" value="https://{yourAccount}.blob.core.windows.net"/>
    <add key="AzureCDNUploadEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="AzureCDNCacheControlHeader" value="must-revalidate, public, max-age=604800"/> <!-- change to whatever suits you -->
    <!-- end cdn -->
```

This is the EventHandler:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Events;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace utest1.umbracoExtensions.events
{
    public class SaveMediaToAzure : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        /* either add your own logging class or remove this and all calls to 'log' */
        private log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(utest1.logging.PublicLogger));

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        private string blobContainerName;
        CloudBlobClient blobClient;
        CloudBlobContainer container;
        string cacheControlHeader;

        private bool uploadEnabled;

        public SaveMediaToAzure()
        {
            try
            {
                storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureCDNStorageConnectionString"]);
                blobContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureCDNStorageAccountName"];
                blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureCDNBlobContainerName"]);
                uploadEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureCDNUploadEnabled"]);
                cacheControlHeader = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureCDNCacheControlHeader"];

                MediaService.Saved += MediaServiceSaved;
                MediaService.Trashed += MediaServiceTrashed;
                MediaService.Deleted += MediaServiceDeleted; // not firing
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                log.Error("SaveMediaToAzure Config Error", x);
            }
        }

        void MediaServiceSaved(IMediaService sender, SaveEventArgs<IMedia> e)
        {
            if (uploadEnabled)
            {
                foreach (var fileItem in e.SavedEntities)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        log.Info("Saving media to Azure:" + e.SavedEntities.First().Name);
                        var path = fileItem.GetValue("umbracoFile").ToString();
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

                        UploadToAzure(filePath, path);

                        if (fileItem.GetType() == typeof(Umbraco.Core.Models.Media))
                        {
                            UploadThumbToAzure(filePath, path);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {
                        log.Error("Error saving media to Azure: " + fileItem.Name, x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * Using this because MediaServiceDeleted event is not firing in v6.1.6
         * 
         */

        void MediaServiceTrashed(IMediaService sender, MoveEventArgs<IMedia> e)
        {
            if (uploadEnabled)
            {
                try
                {
                    log.Info("Deleting media from Azure:" + e.Entity.Name);
                    var path = e.Entity.GetValue("umbracoFile").ToString();
                    CloudBlockBlob imageBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StripContainerNameFromPath(path));
                    imageBlob.Delete();
                    CloudBlockBlob thumbBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StripContainerNameFromPath(GetThumbPath(path)));
                    thumbBlob.Delete();

                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    log.Error("Error deleting media from Azure: " + e.Entity.Name, x);
                }
            }

        }

        /*
         * MediaServiceDeleted event not firing in v6.1.6
         * 
         */

        void MediaServiceDeleted(IMediaService sender, DeleteEventArgs<IMedia> e)
        {
            //if (uploadEnabled)
            //{
            //    try
            //    {
            //        log.Info("Deleting media from Azure:" + e.DeletedEntities.First().Name);
            //        var path = e.DeletedEntities.First().GetValue("umbracoFile").ToString();
            //        CloudBlockBlob imageBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StripContainerNameFromPath(path));
            //        imageBlob.Delete();
            //        CloudBlockBlob thumbBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StripContainerNameFromPath(GetThumbPath(path)));
            //        thumbBlob.Delete();
            //    }
            //    catch (Exception x)
            //    {
            //        log.Error("Error deleting media from Azure: " + e.DeletedEntities.First().Name, x);
            //    }
            //}

            Console.WriteLine(e.DeletedEntities.First().Name);  // still not working

        }

        private string StripContainerNameFromPath(string path)
        {
            return path.Replace("/media/", String.Empty);
        }

        /*
         * 
         * 
         */

        private void UploadToAzure(string filePath, string relativePath)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream data = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.IO.Stream str = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);

            str.CopyTo(data);
            data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] buf = new byte[data.Length];
            data.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            Stream stream = data as Stream;

            if (stream.CanSeek)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StripContainerNameFromPath(relativePath));
                blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                SetCacheControl(blob);
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("Could not read image for upload: " + relativePath);
            }
        }

        private void SetCacheControl(CloudBlockBlob blob)
        {
            blob.Properties.CacheControl = cacheControlHeader;
            blob.SetProperties();
        }

        private void UploadThumbToAzure(string filePath, string relativePath)
        {
            var thumbFilePath = GetThumbPath(filePath);
            var thumbRelativePath = GetThumbPath(relativePath);
            UploadToAzure(thumbFilePath, thumbRelativePath);
        }

        private string GetThumbPath(string path)
        {
            var parts = path.Split('.');
            var filename = parts[parts.Length - 2];
            return path.Replace(filename, filename + "_thumb");
        }

    }
}
```

This is the RenderHelper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace utest1.umbracoExtensions.helpers
{
    public class CDNImage
    {
        public static string ConvertUrlToCDN(string source)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var cdnUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDNPath"];
            var cdnOn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CDNEnabled"];

            if (cdnOn == "true")
            {
                /* 
                 *  check if the url is absolute or not and whether it should be intercepted - eg. an external image url
                 *  if it's absolute you'll need to strip out everything before /media...
                 */

                if (source.Contains(GetBaseUrl()))
                {
                    source = StripBaseUrl(source);
                }

            }

            return source;
        }

        private static string GetBaseUrl()
        {
            var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            var baseUrl = url.Scheme + "//" + url.Host;

            if (url.Port != 80 && url.Port != 443)
            {
                baseUrl += ":" + url.Port;
            }

            return baseUrl;
        }

        private static string StripBaseUrl(string path)
        {
            return path.Replace(GetBaseUrl(), String.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally displaying in the RazorView:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "BasePage.cshtml";
}

@using utest1.umbracoExtensions.helpers

@{

    var ms = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
    var img = ms.GetById(int.Parse(CurrentPage.Image));
}

<h1>Umbraco on Azure is getting there!</h1>
<p>@img.Name</p>
<img alt="@img.Name" src="@CDNImage.ConvertUrlToCDN(img.GetValue("umbracoFile").ToString())" />
```

Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Aaaah, it feels good to give back :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that I spend hours trying to find the answer and then find it soon after I post?

The issue was two fold:

1) I should've been implementing IFileSystem (took inspiration from AmazonS3Provider source)

2) the parameter name being passed from FileSystemProviders.config file was not included in the constructor

Comment: Nugget, would you be kind enough to share your solution please?

Comment: @Steve, not sure how I missed this reply from so long ago. But for the benefit of anyone else coming along here, I abandoned using the FileSystemProvider because I found the Media Upload controls were not using this class for file operations anyway! When using Azure Websites (which have persistent shared disk), you can hook into the MediaService.Saved method and copy to Azure Storage from there.  I also wired up the MediaService.Deleted event but found it wasn't firing on my installation of v6.1.6. So I used the Trashed event instead which means editors need to re-upload if they trash an item.